# Failed resolution of variadic parameter types with post-positioned std::index_sequence

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Assume a sequence of variadic parameter types is to be generated according to a index sequence, i.e, given  a tuple

```cpp
using Tuple = std::tuple<int, float, bool>;
```

and a function signature as following:

```cpp
template <std::size_t ...Is>
void func(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...) {}
```

a invocation like `func(std::make_index_sequence<2>(), 2, 1.0)` would compile without problem.

However, if we were to compute the size of `std::index_sequence` according to another type, and therefore place `std::index_sequence` at the end of parameter list with a default argument, just like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ...Is>
void func(T, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>..., std::index_sequence<Is...> = std::make_index_sequence<some_computation_v<T>>()) {}
```

The compilation of g++ and clang++ would succeed if and only if the size of `std::index_sequence` is 0, that is, for following signature:

```cpp
template <std::size_t... Is>
void func(std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>..., std::index_sequence<Is...> = std::make_index_sequence<2>()) {}
```

`func(2, 1.0)` or `func(2, 1.0, std::make_index_sequence<2>())` would result in error:

```
main.cpp:34:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:43:16: note:   mismatched types ‘std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, _Idx ...>’ and ‘int’
     func(2, 1.0);
```

This prevents me from restricting the types of variadic template with a key type T, by mapping T to a tuple of parameter types and expand it using `std::index_sequence`.

Is there any way to resolve this error or to meet the needs mentioned above?

Comment: But you have to deduce the type `T` from an argument of type `T` or you can pass the type `T` calling the function (something as `func<int>(2, 1.0);`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a "is prefix of types" trait.  Use it in a requires clause.

```
template<class T0>
struct is_tuple_prefix_helper{
    template<class T1>
    static std::false_type test(T1 const&);
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...T0s>
struct is_tuple_prefix_helper<Z<T0s...>>{
    template<class T1>
    static std::false_type test(T1 const&);
    template<class...T1s>
    static std::true_type test(Z<T0s...,T1s...> const&);
};

template<class T0, class T1>
constexpr bool is_tuple_prefix_v=decltype( is_tuple_prefix_helper<T0>::test(std::declval<T1>()) )::value;
```

Then

```
using tup=std::tuple<int,char,double>

template<class...Ts> requires( is_tuple_prefix_v<std::tuple<Ts...>, tup> )
void restricted_func(Ts const&...);
```

should work.

The problem you have is that you are asking to invert a compile time type mapping.  C++ will not invert most compile time type mappings for you; doing so in general is HALT-hard, so C++ does not try.  It will do basic pattern matching, that is all.

This allows you to write a Turing-complete inversion or test, but you have to write it.

This is [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) based.  An earlier version of C++ would instead use SFINAE and other less elegant machinery to do the same thing.  In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
template<class...Ts,
  std::enable_if_t< is_tuple_prefix_v<std::tuple<Ts...>, tup>, bool > =true
>
void restricted_func(Ts const&...);
```

How that exactly works is crazy black magic, honestly.  There is a reason they added `requires` in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20).

Comment: `std::is_same<std::tuple<Ts...>, tup>` might be enough.

Comment: @jarod42 the OP's example uses prefixes; first two elements of the tuple when the tuple has 3 elements.  But yes, I have seen bad problem specifications that ask for X when they want Y, and Y is both much easier and better for them.

Comment: I didn't notice OP used 2 arguments on 3... ^_^

Comment: BTW, as C++20 is still recent, I would mention that `requires` is C++20 (and "old" `std::enable_if` might be used instead for oldest standard).

Comment: @Jarod42 I threw in a pre-20 version.  I used [tag:C++14] because the further back you go, the more annoying the syntax goes.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the answer, I had decided to not use X, but asked with above problem specification just to learn why the error occurs and what I did wrong here...this is indeed a bad specification though.

Comment: I was trying to use X with the expectation that it would provide better intellisense, i.e., if I type the key argument of type T, would the language server then automatically provide the rest parameter types deduced from T for me?

Comment: @Vigilans If you want to create a callable object using the types of a Tuple as arguments that intellisense understands, that is a different problem, and it can't be a non-member (static or not) function.  That is a different question, and it is probably worth asking by pressing the [ask question] button.

Answer (score 2):

In `std::tuple_element<Is, Tuple>::type`, `Is` is non deducible. default function argument doesn't participate in the deduction or parameter's types, so entire pack is empty.

You might still write helper function to have expected API order:

```
template <std::size_t ...Is>
void func_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...)
{
// ...
}

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
auto func(T, Ts&&... args)
// possibly decltype return type for SFINAE
{
    return func_impl(std::make_index_sequence<some_computation_v<T>>(),
                     std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```